# SQL Server connection with C# -> does a database exist?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

In a small application I'm making for school, I'm attempting to determine if the necessary database exists.

If it does not, I want to create it (along with the tables in the database), and then use it as normal.

I'm using Visual C# Express Edition, along with SQL Server Express. I wrote the small test program below...

```
namespace DatabaseConnectionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static SqlConnection con;

        public static void EstablishConnection()
        {
            string userName = "username";
            string password = "password";
            string server = @".\SQLEXPRESS";
            string database = "Blibbity";
            string trustedConnection = "yes";
            string timeout = "30";

            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(
                        "user id=" + userName +
                        ";password=" + password +
                        ";server=" + server +
                        ";Trusted_Connection=" + trustedConnection +
                        ";database=" + database +
                        ";connection timeout=" + timeout);
                con.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");

                var command = new SqlCommand("insert into sometable values ('somedata')", con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert successful!");

                command = new SqlCommand("select somecolumn from sometable", con);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fectched data ====> " + reader["somecolumn"].ToString());
                }

                reader.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Query successful!");

                command = new SqlCommand("delete from sometable where somecolumn = 'somedata'", con);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Delete successful!");
            }
            catch
            {
                database = "master";

                con = new SqlConnection(
                    "user id=" + userName +
                    ";password=" + password +
                    ";server=" + server +
                    ";Trusted_Connection=" + trustedConnection +
                    ";database=" + database +
                    ";connection timeout=" + timeout);

                con.Open();

                var command = new SqlCommand(@"
                    USE [master]
                    GO

                    /****** Object:  Database [Blibbity]    Script Date: 04/12/2012 07:08:45 ******/
                    CREATE DATABASE [Blibbity] ON  PRIMARY 
                    ( NAME = N'Blibbity', FILENAME = N'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Blibbity.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
                     LOG ON 
                    ( NAME = N'Blibbity_log', FILENAME = N'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Blibbity_log.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
                    GO

                    IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
                    begin
                    EXEC [Blibbity].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
                    end
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET  READ_WRITE 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET  MULTI_USER 
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
                    GO

                    ALTER DATABASE [Blibbity] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
                    GO", con);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                database = "Blibbity";

                con = new SqlConnection(
                    "user id=" + userName +
                    ";password=" + password +
                    ";server=" + server +
                    ";Trusted_Connection=" + trustedConnection +
                    ";database=" + database +
                    ";connection timeout=" + timeout);

                con.Open();

                command = new SqlCommand(@"
                    USE [Blibbity]
                    GO

                    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[sometable]    Script Date: 04/12/2012 07:09:07 ******/
                    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
                    GO

                    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
                    GO

                    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
                    GO

                    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sometable](
                        [somecolumn] [varchar](50) NULL
                    ) ON [PRIMARY]

                    GO

                    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
                    GO", con);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                EstablishConnection();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection now closed...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EstablishConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously `Blibbity` is just a junk database. It's when I hit the first `ExecuteNonQuery()` line in the exception catch, it tells me that my syntax near `"GO"` is incorrect, yet I just copied the text for the database/table creation using SQL Server Management Studio's "Script As CREATE TO" feature.

Does anybody know why I'm running into this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: As a side tip: if you want to create a connection string from a set of parameters, I would use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class which is designed specifically for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GO is not a sql server command, it is interpreted by Management studio. If you want to achieve the same behavior, than you have to split the sql command by the go instructions and execute each part sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating database manually I would suggest you use Entity Framework which in code-first approach has a built in support for creating a new database if it doesn't exist, adding tables and even populating them with initial data.

So instead of looking for a solution to your problem you can remove the problem itself.